# Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce() custom api plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Whenever I attempt to activate my plugin, I consistently encounter that error. Regardless of the steps I take to rectify it, the issue persists.

Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce() wp-async-request.php:136

This plugin is designed for a product API. Its primary function is to generate a products.json file containing all the products obtained from the API. Subsequently, it should proceed to create or modify the corresponding products within WooCommerce. However, I am encountering an obstacle in this process.

I am utilizing WP Background Processing to enhance the efficiency of product loading. i used wp cron first with batches, but that caused a time out so i tried to utilize wp background processing.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Fixjeiphone B2B Integration
 * Description: Fixje API product koppeling
 * Version: 3.2
 * Author: Ayman
 */

// This function will be called after all plugins have loaded
function initialize_fixjeiphone_integration() {
    global $fixjeiphone_products_process;
    
    // Include your class files
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/background-processing/wp-async-request.php';
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/background-processing/wp-background-process.php';

    // Initialize global variables and class instances
    $fixjeiphone_products_process = new Fixjeiphone_Products_Process();

    // Add all your initialization actions here
    add_action('init', 'initialize_fixjeiphone_background_process');
    add_action('wp_loaded', 'dispatch_fixjeiphone_background_process');
    add_action('admin_notices', 'fixjeiphone_admin_notice');
    add_action('admin_menu', 'fixjeiphone_add_admin_menu');
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'fixjeiphone_enqueue_admin_scripts');
    add_action('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook', 'fixjeiphone_process_products');
    add_action('wp_ajax_fixjeiphone_start_synchronization', 'fixjeiphone_start_synchronization_ajax');    
    // More custom initialization as needed...
}

// Hook the initialization function to the 'plugins_loaded' action
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'initialize_fixjeiphone_integration');

// Before requiring the WP_Background_Process, check if WP_Async_Request is already defined.
if (!class_exists('WP_Async_Request')) {
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/background-processing/wp-async-request.php';
}

// Now, ensure WP_Background_Process is also defined before requiring it.
if (!class_exists('WP_Background_Process')) {
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/background-processing/wp-background-process.php';
}

 class Fixjeiphone_Products_Process extends WP_Background_Process {

    protected $action = 'fixjeiphone_process_products';

    protected function task($product) {
        // Assume $woocommerce is your WooCommerce client instance.
        $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    
        if (isset($product['sku'])) {
            // Format the product attributes and other details as before.
            $attributes = formatProductAttributes(isset($product['attributes']) ? $product['attributes'] : []);
            $finalProduct = [
                'name' => $product['name'],
                'slug' => $product['slug'],
                'type' => $product['type'],
                'sku' => $product['sku'],
                'regular_price' => isset($product['price']) ? strval($product['price']) : '',
                'manage_stock' => true,
                'stock_quantity' => isset($product['stock']) ? $product['stock'] : 0,
                'weight' => isset($product['weight']) ? $product['weight'] : '',
                'dimensions' => [
                    'length' => isset($product['dimensions']['length']) ? $product['dimensions']['length'] : '',
                    'width' => isset($product['dimensions']['width']) ? $product['dimensions']['width'] : '',
                    'height' => isset($product['dimensions']['height']) ? $product['dimensions']['height'] : ''
                ],
                'attributes' => $attributes
            ];
    
            try {
                $existingProduct = getProductBySKU($woocommerce, $product['sku']);
                if ($existingProduct) {
                    // Update the existing product with new details from $finalProduct.
                    $woocommerce->put('products/' . $existingProduct->id, $finalProduct);
                    error_log('Updating existing product: ' . $product['sku']);
                } else {
                    // Create a new product with details from $finalProduct.
                    $woocommerce->post('products', $finalProduct);
                    error_log('Creating new product: ' . $product['sku']);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log('Error updating/creating product ' . $product['sku'] . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                // Optionally, re-queue the product for later attempt or log this issue.
            }
    
            // Return false to signal this product is done processing and remove from the queue.
            return false;
        }
    
        // If product doesn't have a SKU or there was an issue, you might choose to requeue or simply drop by returning false.
        return false;
    }
}

// Initialize global variable outside any function.
global $fixjeiphone_products_process;
$fixjeiphone_products_process = new Fixjeiphone_Products_Process();

function initialize_fixjeiphone_background_process() {
    global $fixjeiphone_products_process;
    // Your product fetching and queuing logic here.
    // For example, directly reading from the JSON and adding to queue:

    $productsJson = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/uploads/products.json');
    if ($productsJson === false) {
        error_log('Failed to read products.json file.');
        return; // Exit the function if unable to read file.
    }

    $allProducts = json_decode($productsJson, true);
    if (!is_array($allProducts)) {
        error_log("Decoded data is not an array. JSON decoding error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        return; // Exit the function if JSON is not valid.
    }

    foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
        $fixjeiphone_products_process->push_to_queue($product);
    }
    $fixjeiphone_products_process->save()->dispatch();
}



function dispatch_fixjeiphone_background_process() {
    global $fixjeiphone_products_process;
    if (isset($fixjeiphone_products_process)) {
        $fixjeiphone_products_process->save()->dispatch();
    }
}

// Register activation and deactivation hooks
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'fixjeiphone_activation_hook');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'fixjeiphone_deactivation_hook');

// Add admin notice and admin menu

// Enqueue admin scripts
function fixjeiphone_enqueue_admin_scripts($hook) {
    if ('toplevel_page_fixjeiphone-b2b-integration' !== $hook) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('fixjeiphone-admin-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/admin-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('fixjeiphone-admin-script', 'fixjeiphoneAjax', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('fixjeiphone_ajax_nonce')  // Create a specific nonce for your action
    ));
}

function fixjeiphone_release_lock() {
    delete_option('fixjeiphone_processing_products');
    remove_action('shutdown', 'fixjeiphone_release_lock'); // Remove the shutdown action to avoid unnecessary calls
}



// Admin notice
function fixjeiphone_admin_notice() {
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')) { // Check if the current user is an administrator
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php _e('Fixjeiphone B2B Integration is activated. Please go to the settings page to start the synchronization.', 'fixjeiphone-b2b-integration'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

// Admin menu
function fixjeiphone_add_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Fixjeiphone B2B Integration', 'Fixjeiphone B2B', 'manage_options', 'fixjeiphone-b2b-integration', 'fixjeiphone_settings_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic', 6);
}

// Settings page
function fixjeiphone_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Fixjeiphone B2B Integration', 'fixjeiphone-b2b-integration'); ?></h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('fixjeiphone_plugin_settings'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('fixjeiphone_plugin_settings'); ?>
            <button type="button" class="button-primary" id="startSynchronizationButton"><?php _e('Start Synchronization', 'fixjeiphone-b2b-integration'); ?></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#startSynchronizationButton').click(function() {
            alert('<?php _e("Starting synchronization...", "fixjeiphone-b2b-integration"); ?>');
            $.ajax({
                url: fixjeiphoneAjax.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'fixjeiphone_start_synchronization',
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response.message);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert('<?php _e("Error starting synchronization", "fixjeiphone-b2b-integration"); ?>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Activation hook function
function fixjeiphone_activation_hook() {
    // Schedule the first event if it's not already scheduled
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'fixjeiphone_process_products_hook');
    }
}

// Deactivation hook function
function fixjeiphone_deactivation_hook() {
    if (wp_next_scheduled('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook')) {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook');
    }
}

function fixjeiphone_plugin_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook');
    // Additional deactivation tasks.
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'fixjeiphone_plugin_deactivation');


error_log('Starting product batch processing at ' . current_time('mysql'));

function fixjeiphone_start_synchronization_ajax() {
    // Verify the nonce first
    check_ajax_referer('fixjeiphone_ajax_nonce');

    // Your synchronization logic here

    wp_send_json_success(array('message' => __('Synchronization started successfully.', 'fixjeiphone-b2b-integration')));
}

// Schedule next batch
function schedule_next_batch() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 30, 'fixjeiphone_process_products_hook'); // Adjust the 30 seconds as needed.
    }
}

// Setup your client credentials
$clientID = 'NVT';
$clientSecret = 'NVT';
  $token;
  $expiresIn;
  $token_type;
  $scope;

// Set the token request params
$tokenParams =[
'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
'client_id' => urldecode($clientID),
'client_secret'=> urldecode($clientSecret),
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.fixje.nl/wp-json/b2bapi/v1/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tokenParams));



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$arrayResponse = json_decode($response, TRUE);

if ($httpCode == 200 && $arrayResponse != null) {
  $token = $arrayResponse['access_token'];
  $expiresIn = $arrayResponse['expires_in'];
  $token_type = $arrayResponse['token_type'];
  $scope = $arrayResponse['scope'];
}


curl_close($ch);

var_dump(
  $arrayResponse
);


// Get all products
$getProduct = curl_init();

curl_setopt($getProduct, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.fixje.nl/wp-json/b2bapi/v1/products");
curl_setopt($getProduct, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($getProduct, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($getProduct, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Authorization: Bearer $token"
));

$GetProductResponse = curl_exec($getProduct);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($getProduct, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($getProduct);

// Decode the JSON response into a PHP array
$productsArray = json_decode($GetProductResponse, true);

// Check if decoding was successful and response includes products
if ($http_status == 200 && is_array($productsArray)) {
    // Loop through each product in the array
    foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
        // Process each product. For example, log product name
        // (Replace this with whatever processing you need to do with each product)
        echo "Processing product: " . $product['name'] . "\n";
        // Here you could add code to create/update products in WooCommerce
    }

    // Save the JSON data to the file
    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/uploads/products.json';
    file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($productsArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));  // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT for easier reading
    echo "Data saved to $filePath";

} else {
    // Handle errors or unexpected response formats
    echo "Failed to fetch products or received invalid response";
}

// Woocommerce functions
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;


function getWoocommerceConfig() {
    return new Automattic\WooCommerce\Client(
        'https://swapphone.nl', // Ensure this URL is correct
        'nvt', 
        'nvt',
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v3', // Updated to v3
            'query_string_auth' => false,
            'verify_ssl' => true, // True by default, change if testing SSL issues
            'timeout' => 60 // Increase timeout to 30 seconds
        ]
    );
    return $woocommerce;
}



/**
 * Parse JSON file.
 *
 * @param  string $file
 * @return array
 */
function getJsonFromFile()
{
    $file = __DIR__ . '/uploads/products.json';
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    return $json;
}


function checkProductBySku($skuCode)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $products = $woocommerce->get('products');
    if (is_wp_error($products)) {
    // Log error or handle it appropriately
    return ['exist' => false, 'idProduct' => null];
}

    // Convert the SKU code to lowercase for consistent comparison
    $skuCode = strtolower($skuCode);

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        // Access product properties using object syntax
        $productSKU = strtolower($product->sku); // Also convert this SKU to lowercase

        // Compare the product SKU with the provided SKU code
        if ($productSKU === $skuCode)
        {
            // Return the product information if a match is found
            return ['exist' => true, 'idProduct' => $product->id];
        }
    }

    // Return false if no matching product is found
    return ['exist' => false, 'idProduct' => null];
}

/// talla
function getproductAtributesNames($articulos)
{
 
 /*'attributes' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'talla',
                        'slug' => 'attr_var_mattress_hardness',
                        'visible' => true,
                        'variation' => true,
                        'options' => array(
                            'hard', 'medium', 'soft'
                        )
                    )
                )*/


    $keys = array();


    foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
        {

        $terms = $articulo['config'];
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term)
            {
            array_push($keys, $key);
        }


    }
   /* remove repeted keys*/
    $keys = array_unique($keys);
    $configlist = array_column($articulos, 'config');


    $options = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key)
        {
   /*(getTermsByKeyName($key, $configlist));*/
        $attributes = array(
            array(
                'name' => $key,
                'slug' => 'attr_' . $key,
                'visible' => true,
                'variation' => true,
                'options' => getTermsByKeyName($key, $configlist)
            )
        );

    }

    return $attributes;

}


function getTermsByKeyName($keyName, $configList)
{
 //var_dump($configList);
    $options = array();
    foreach ($configList as $config)
        {


        foreach ($config as $key => $term)
            {
            if ($key == $keyName)
                {
                array_push($options, $term);
            }
        }

    }
    return $options;
}



function formatProductAttributes($attributes) {
    $formattedAttributes = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $formattedOptions = [];
        foreach ($attribute['options'] as $option) {
            $formattedOptions[] = $option; // Collect all options
        }
        $formattedAttributes[] = [
            'id' => $attribute['id'],
            'name' => $attribute['name'],
            'option' => $formattedOptions,
            'visible' => true,
            'variation' => $attribute['variation']
        ];
    }
    return $formattedAttributes;
}

// Define the function to get a product by SKU
function getProductBySKU($woocommerce, $sku) {
    try {
        $products = $woocommerce->get('products', ['sku' => $sku]);
        if (!empty($products)) {
            return $products[0];
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function createProducts() {
    global $fixjeiphone_products_process; // Ensure this is defined somewhere globally accessible

    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    error_log('Starting createProducts function');

    // Instead of loading and processing all products from a JSON file directly,
    // we add them to a background processing queue.
    $productsJson = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/uploads/products.json');
    if ($productsJson === false) {
        error_log('Failed to read products.json file.');
        return; // Exit the function if unable to read file
    }

    $allProducts = json_decode($productsJson, true);
    if (!is_array($allProducts)) {
        error_log("Decoded data is not an array. JSON decoding error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        return; // Exit the function if JSON is not valid
    }

    // Add each product to the background processing queue
    foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
        $fixjeiphone_products_process->push_to_queue($product);
    }

    // Dispatch the background process to handle these products
    $fixjeiphone_products_process->save()->dispatch();
    error_log('All products have been added to the background processing queue.');
}

add_action('fixjeiphone_process_products_hook', 'createProducts');

function createProductVariations($productId, $variations)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
 /*
  array(5) {
    ["precio"]=>
    float(28.95)
    ["descuento"]=>
    int(10)
    ["impuesto"]=>
    int(13)
    ["existencias"]=>
    int(0)
    ["config"]=>
    array(1) {
     ["talla"]=>
     string(1) "M"
    }
 }
     */

    foreach ($variations as $variation)
        {
        $attributes[] = $variation['config'];
    }


    $data = [
  /*'sale_price' => $variation['precio'],*/
        'stock_quantity' => $variation['existencias'],
        'attributes' => $attributes,
    ];

    $woocommerce->post('products/' . $productId . '/variations', $data);
}

function getAtributeId($attributeName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $attributes = $woocommerce->get('products/attributes');
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
        {
        if ($attribute['name'] === $attributeName)
            {
            return $attribute['id'];
        }
    }
}
function checkAttributes($attributeName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $currentattributes = $woocommerce->get('products/attributes');
    foreach ($currentattributes as $currentattribute)
        {
        $attributeSlug = strtolower($currentattribute['name']);
        $attributeName = strtolower($attributeName);
        if ($attributeSlug === $attributeName)
            {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


function createAttributes()
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $products = getJsonFromFile();
    foreach ($products as $product)
        {
        $articulos = $product['articulos'];


        foreach ($articulos as $config)
            {
            $attributeNames = array_keys($config['config']);

            foreach ($attributeNames as $attributenName)
                {
                if (checkAttributes($attributenName) == false)
                    {
                    $data = [
                        'name' => $attributenName,
                        'slug' => $attributenName,
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'order_by' => 'menu_order',
                        'has_archives' => true
                    ];
                    $resultAttributes = $woocommerce->post('products/attributes', $data);
                    createAtrributeTerms($resultAttributes['id'], $attributenName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function createAtrributeTerms($idTerm, $attributeName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $products = getJsonFromFile();
    $articulos = array_column($products, 'articulos');

    foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
        {
        foreach ($articulo as $config)
            {
            $configurations = $config['config'];

            foreach ($configurations as $config)
                {
                $listTerms[] = $config;
            }
        }
    }
    $listTerms = array_unique($listTerms);
    foreach ($listTerms as $term)
        {
        $data = [
            'name' => $term
        ];
        $woocommerce->post('products/attributes/' . $idTerm . '/terms', $data);
    }
}




/** CATEGORIES  **/
function getCategories() {
    $products = getJsonFromFile();
    $categories = array_column($products, 'categorias');
    $categoryPlainValues = []; // Initialize as empty array

    foreach ($categories as $categoryItems) {
        foreach ($categoryItems as $categoryValue) {
            $categoryPlainValues[] = $categoryValue;
        }
    }
    $categoryList = array_unique($categoryPlainValues);
    return $categoryList;
}



function createCategories()
{
    $categoryValues = getCategories();
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
 
 /* Add a category verificator */
    foreach ($categoryValues as $value)
        {
        if (!checkCategoryByname($value))
            {
            $data = [
                'name' => $value
            ];
            print_r($woocommerce->post('products/categories', $data));
        }
    }
}

function checkCategoryByName($categoryName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $categories = $woocommerce->get('products/categories');
    foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
        if ($category['name'] === $categoryName)
            {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getCategoryIdByName($categoryName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $categories = $woocommerce->get('products/categories');
    foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
        if ($category['name'] == $categoryName)
            {
            return $category['id'];
        }
    }
}
function assignCategoriestoProduct($idproduct, $idcategory)
{

}


function prepareInitialConfig()
{
    /**$woocommerce= getWoocommerceConfig(); 45
 print_r($woocommerce->get('products/attributes'));*/

    echo ('<h1>Importing data....</h1>');
    echo ('<br>');
 /*createAttributes();*/
 /* Create categories */
    createCategories();
 /* get all categories*/
    createProducts();
    echo ('<br>');
    echo ('</h1>Done!</h1>');
}

prepareInitialConfig();


?>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible for us to know what's wrong. Check the links brombeer shared above to learn what you need to do in order for us to be able to help.

Comment: I would suggest you to make a [mre], so a minimal example, but at least now we have you're code :)